# How to append content to a textarea after modifying manually its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an input and textarea, and I'm capturing the enter on the input and I'm appending that line to the textarea, this works fine, but when I make some edition directly on the textarea like delete or insert some text, the programatic insert doesn't work anymore. How can I fix this?

I've tested this in Chrome 53, Firefox 49.0.2 and Opera 40, so it seems that's not a browser problem. Here a code that I've tried to work with:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="entry" name="entry"><br>
<textarea id="result" rows="10"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#entry").on("keyup", function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13){
    $("#result").append( $("#entry").val()+"\n");    
    $("#entry").val("");
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to get textarea to not lose the reference of the value is save it, and then concat the existing value of the new entry, see below for an example:

```js
$("#entry").on("keyup", function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13){
    var text = $("#result").val();
    $("#result").val( text +  $("#entry").val()+"\n");    
    $("#entry").val("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="entry" name="entry"><br>
<textarea id="result" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: alternate syntax:`var text = $("#result").val()+  $("#entry").val()+"\n"; $("#result").val( text);`

Comment: Might also get some context with `this` as with `$("#result").val($("#result").val() + $(this).val() + "\n");
    $(this).val("");`

Answer (score 3):

You can also you [jQuery#val-function](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function):

```js
$("#entry").on("keyup", function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13){
    $("#result").val(function(i, txt) {
      return txt + $("#entry").val() + "\n";
    });
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="entry" name="entry"><br>
<textarea id="result" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: `$(this).val(` rather `$("#entry").val(` in those places?